# Errors compiling Rosjava code

Tags: ros, namespace, topic, rosjava, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having a compiler issue while running rosjava.  I am attempting to compile a piece of java code using javac along with adding org.apache.commons.logging third party Java library to my classpath, but I am receiving the following messages:

"package org.ros.namespace does not exist"
"package org.ros.node does not exist"
"package org.ros.node.topic does not exist"

Would you know by any chance what could be causing this issue or if I am even compiling the java code correctly?  The code is in the "robot" subdirectory within my "rosjava" directory in a third subdirectory called "src".  I am currently running on the Hydro distribution of Java.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131531/errors-compiling-rosjava-code/) by [musik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5129/musik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2014-02-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-02-20**:
What instructions are you following to build?

**Comment by [musik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5129/musik/) on 2014-02-20**:
I'm using instructions from: http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_ROSJava_to_Program_the_iRobot_Create_to_Move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like your internal documentation was for fuerte. Consequently the rosjava wiki page instructions will be out of sync with your internal wiki instructions (ros went through big build system changes from fuerte -> hydro). RosJava also moved from google code to github.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [musik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5129/musik/) on 2014-02-20**:
OK. Are there updated instructions on how to compile and run this sort of code, or would I have to revert back to fuerte on my machine? I have a fuerte distribution from a previous download.